# Submit transaction to multiple endorsing peers using composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a business network with 2 Orgs, and each Org have one peer. According to my endorsement policy that I've used to start the network both Orgs must endorse transactions.

According to the Hyperledger Fabric docs [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/txflow.html) and FAQs [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/Fabric-FAQ.html#endorsement) the client should connect to each endorsing peer and submit a transaction to both.

Composer has `transaction submit` command which allows to submit a transaction to the business network. But referring to docs [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.transaction.submit.html) there is no parameters to specify the peers to which client should connect. Actually, when I submit the transaction this way using the admin card of one Org, I get `ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE` error. The same situation happens when I submit transaction through the Composer REST server.

Is there any way to submit a transaction using composer to multiple peers for endorsing?

Comment: yes. The [multi-org tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) does exactly that - but remember the peers are defined in the connection profile (that is, whatever peers you define to represent both orgs) - and not provided as a parameter to the `composer transaction submit' trxn or as some option in the REST API.  Step Two /Step Three has the connection profile (for an admin from org1 - Step Four for org2 etc)...contd..

Comment: ..then scroll down to Step Thirteen (or search for 'endorsement') to see the endorsement policy which is supplied as a parameter to the `composer network start` (business network start on the channel).

Comment: I'm following that multi-org tutorial adopting it according to my needs. So, does `composer transaction submit` submit tx to all the peers that should endorse that transaction (if that peers are defined with `"endorsingPeer": true` in the connection profile)?

Comment: Composer will send the transaction to all the Peers in your connection.json document. `endorsingPeer` means that peer is there to endorse transactions (to do that, it must have chaincode instantiated). An endorsing peer in Fabric, is the peer which has chaincode installed on it, hence able to invoke it and interact with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I know, that the issue is not with the endorsement policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Paul O'Mahony for helping to understand what `composer transaction submit` command does (see the comments below the question):

> Composer will send the transaction to all the Peers in your connection.json document.

Initially I made a wrong assumption that the issue was with the endorsement policy. Actually, my problem was with access rules. A participant had no rights to create that transaction. Correcting the ACL file fixed the issue.